# mkdocs nginx reverse proxy slow

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, read-the-docs, mkdocs

I have setup mkdocs and running on port 8000, Nginx is setup as reverse proxy with below configuration. However when accessing the site through reverse proxy browser stays "connecting..." for a long time approx 2 mins and page loads. Also if I stop with "X" with the browser, entire page shows up immediately. Could anyone help on this please?

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name docs.example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
  }
}
```

And nginx.conf is

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

Comment: Anyone can help please

Comment: Are you sure it's listening on lo0? Have you tried `nc 127.0.0.1 8000`?

Comment: @tjvr yes I can curl and get the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MkDocs is a ***static*** site generator.

The intended use case is that you "build" your pages as [static web pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_web_page) and then upload the already built HTML pages to your server where the server serves them up to your users. A major advantage is that as the server does not need to reprocess the Markdown and templates for each request, it is much faster.

While it is true that MkDocs does include a `serve` command, the included "server" is intended for development only. In other words, when writing your documents you can use the development server to see your changes live on your local machine. However, the server is not intended to serve anything to other machines or the outside world. It was never anticipated that the server would have multiple simultaneous connections.

So rather than having nginx listing on a port, you should point it at a directory of static files and copy a build of your MkDocs documents to that directory.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense. I was able to build with the documentation from site. I din't know serve was intended for developing purpose only :)